# Javascript call to chain constructors for an object

Tags: javascript

1) call

```
var obj = {num:2};

var add = function(a){
    return this.num + a;
};

add.call(obj, 1); //function.call(obj, arg)
```

2) call to chain constructors for an object.

```
var Product = function (name, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}

var Food = function(name, price) {
    Product.call(this, name, price); // <-- 1. Product is obj constructor not fun
                                     //     2. what is 'this' here?
    this.category = 'food';
}

var cheese = new Food('feta', 5);

console.dir(cheese);
```

I'm currently study javascript oop, I found an example about `Function.prototype.call()` chain constructors, but I don't understand how it works.

1) isn't call required function call obj? but Product is construct.

```
var food = { category : 'food' };

var Product = function (name, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}

var cheese = Product.call(food);
console.dir(cheese);//this will become undefine
```

2) what is 'this'? Food object? `Product.call(new Food, name, price);`?

*final result `var cheese` will be an object, `Product.call(new Food obj, name, price)`

Product still a function, why result become an object?

Comment: `this` would point to `Food`

Comment: its really confuse, because Food is a constructor and we create a new Food object, and inside contain call

Comment: i'm getting confuse on those, we have function, method and Constructor, what is function as class?

Comment: @Rajesh, Food *is* a constructor, since it can be (and is) called with the `new` keyword. What do you mean with "function as class"? It is not a term used in the EcmaScript specs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both *Product* and *Food* are used as constructors, which means nothing more than that they are functions, and they can be called with `new` (but don't necessarily have to). The *Food* constructor makes use of *Product* to extend the object that is created with `new Food(...)`.

It is vital to understand that when you call a function with `new`, a new, empty object is created that is available to that function as `this`. In the function you can then add properties to it. Also, if a function does not have a `return` statement in it, it still will return an object when it is called with `new`: it is the constructed object that is called `this` within the function.

Some magic happens with:

```
Product.call(this, name, price); // <-- 1. Product is construct not fun
```

Normally you would call *Product* like this:

```
new Product(name, price)
```

... but that creates and returns a new object. However, here the purpose is to *extend* the object created with `new Food(...)`. That latter object is `this`. So instead of doing `new Product(...)` (which creates another new object), you pass the already existing object (`this`) to it. That you can do with `.call()`, which expects as the first argument the context -- the object that will be `this` during the *Product* function execution.

Note that in this case `.call` returns `undefined`, because the function is not called with `new`, and so the return value would be whatever the function returns explicitly. As there is no `return` statement in *Product*, it will return `undefined`. But that is of no interest here, as we only look to the side-effect the function call has on the first argument: `this` gets properties assigned to it.

So both the *Product* and the *Food* function get to add properties to the *same* object. When *Food* returns from the `new Food()` call, you'll have an object that is an `instanceof` *Food*.

Note that there are several ways to implement inheritance, and this way of doing it has some downsides, including:

- the resulting object is not considered `instanceof` *Product*, and
- properties which were defined on the `Product.prototype` will not be available to the object created with `new Food()`.

Comment: from 1st example, var add is a function, but 2nd example var Product is not a function, how can u use 'call'? 'call ' should be function.call(object)

Comment: Product is a function. Whether you write `function Product() {...` or `var Product = function() {...`, it is a function. Even if it does not return a value explicitly, it does so when you call it with `new`. And with `Product.call` the return value is not used, instead the side-effect it has on the first argument (the context) is what is important there.

Comment: we call new Food but we don't call new Product, 1. if we call new Product, product will be object( we cant put in obj.call(obj) ), 2. if its function, new Food('feta', 5); shouldn't be object, that is what confuse me

Comment: `new Product()` is indeed a (non-function) object, but `Product` is a function. The first is what you get when you *call* it, the second is the function itself, which is not (yet) called. See the difference? So `Product` has the `call` method. `new Food(...)` will *always* be an object, whatever the function *Food* does, with the exception of a run-time error occurring.

Comment: ok so product is a function, but we didn't return as an object, how come var cheese is an object?

Comment: `cheese` would be an object even if `Food` was an empty function. Like I said, it doesn't matter what `Food` does (do a `Product.call` or not), it will *always* return an object when called with `new`. This is how `new` works. You can even do `var cheese = new function() {};` and you will have created an empty object.